# How can I prevent a wpf ribbon group from fully collapsing without specifying all combinations of size definitions?

Tags: .net, wpf, ribbon

How can I prevent a wpf ribbon group from fully collapsing?

I realise there is a RibbonGroup.GroupSizeDefinitions property (it's discussed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701790.aspx) and if I define a bunch of RibbonGroupSizeDefinition and none with isCollapsed=true it does close to what I want.

Unfortunately I don't want to have to define the size definitions because the buttons shown will vary depending on the users license. eg. one client may get six buttons in a group and one might have four.

So I want it to auto setup the groups but never go into fully collapsed - is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have derived Ribbon, RibbonTab and RibbonGroup.

Instead of rewriting the code of GroupSizeDefinitions, I use reflection to access the GroupSizeDefinitions property.

```
public class xxxRibbon : Ribbon
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new xxxRibbonTab();
    }
}

public class xxxRibbonTab : RibbonTab
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new xxxRibbonGroup();
    }
}

public class xxxRibbonGroup : RibbonGroup
{
    public const string PropertyName_IsCollapsable = "IsCollapsable";
    public const string PropertyName_GroupSizeDefinitionsResourceName = "GroupSizeDefinitionsResourceName";

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCollapsableProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(xxxRibbonGroup.PropertyName_IsCollapsable, typeof(bool), typeof(xxxRibbonGroup), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((bool)true, xxxRibbonGroup.IsCollapsablePropertyChangedCallback));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GroupSizeDefinitionsResourceNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(xxxRibbonGroup.PropertyName_GroupSizeDefinitionsResourceName, typeof(string), typeof(xxxRibbonGroup), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((string)null, xxxRibbonGroup.GroupSizeDefinitionsResourceNamePropertyChangedCallback));

    public bool IsCollapsable
    {
        get { return (bool)this.GetValue(xxxRibbonGroup.IsCollapsableProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(xxxRibbonGroup.IsCollapsableProperty, value); }
    }

    public string GroupSizeDefinitionsResourceName
    {
        get { return (string)this.GetValue(xxxRibbonGroup.GroupSizeDefinitionsResourceNameProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(xxxRibbonGroup.GroupSizeDefinitionsResourceNameProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void IsCollapsablePropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        xxxRibbonGroup ribbonGroup = dependencyObject as xxxRibbonGroup;
        if (ribbonGroup == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        ribbonGroup.rebuildGroupSizeDefinitions();
    }

    private static void GroupSizeDefinitionsResourceNamePropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        xxxRibbonGroup ribbonGroup = dependencyObject as xxxRibbonGroup;
        if (ribbonGroup == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        ribbonGroup.rebuildGroupSizeDefinitions();
    }

    protected override void OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnItemsChanged(e);

        this.GroupSizeDefinitions = null;
        this.rebuildGroupSizeDefinitions();
    }

    protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue)
    {
        base.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);

        this.GroupSizeDefinitions = null;
        this.rebuildGroupSizeDefinitions();
    }

    private void rebuildGroupSizeDefinitions()
    {
        string resourceName = this.GroupSizeDefinitionsResourceName;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceName) == false)
        {
            object resource = Application.Current.TryFindResource(resourceName);
            if (resource == null)
            {
                this.GroupSizeDefinitions = null;
                return;
            }

            RibbonGroupSizeDefinitionBaseCollection grsidef = resource as RibbonGroupSizeDefinitionBaseCollection;
            if (grsidef == null)
            {
                this.GroupSizeDefinitions = null;
                return;
            }

            this.GroupSizeDefinitions = grsidef;
            return;
        }

        PropertyInfo[] props = this.GetType().BaseType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);

        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in props)
        {
            if (propertyInfo.Name == "GroupSizeDefinitionsInternal")
            {
                RibbonGroupSizeDefinitionBaseCollection value = propertyInfo.GetValue(this, BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, null, null) as RibbonGroupSizeDefinitionBaseCollection;
                if ((value != null) && (value.Count > 0))
                {
                    RibbonGroupSizeDefinitionBaseCollection result = new RibbonGroupSizeDefinitionBaseCollection();
                    foreach (RibbonGroupSizeDefinitionBase it in value)
                    {
                        if (this.IsCollapsable == false)
                        {
                            if (it.IsCollapsed == false)
                            {
                                result.Add(it);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result.Add(it);
                        }
                    }

                    result.Freeze();

                    this.GroupSizeDefinitions = result;
                    return;
                }

                return;
            }
        }

        Traceur.Assert(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
<RibbonGroup Name="Clipboard">
   <RibbonGroup.GroupSizeDefinitions>
       <RibbonGroupSizeDefinition>
            <RibbonControlSizeDefinition ImageSize="Large" IsLabelVisible="True" />
            <RibbonControlSizeDefinition ImageSize="Small" IsLabelVisible="True" />
            <RibbonControlSizeDefinition ImageSize="Small" IsLabelVisible="True" />
        </RibbonGroupSizeDefinition>           
           <RibbonGroupSizeDefinition>
             <RibbonControlSizeDefinition ImageSize="Large" IsLabelVisible="True" />
             <RibbonControlSizeDefinition ImageSize="Small" IsLabelVisible="False" />
             <RibbonControlSizeDefinition ImageSize="Small" IsLabelVisible="False" />
           </RibbonGroupSizeDefinition>
          <RibbonGroupSizeDefinition IsCollapsed="False" />
    </RibbonGroup.GroupSizeDefinitions>
 <RibbonGroup>
```

Will never collapse anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I see the ribbon source code is available for download http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=11877

From here I am able to look inside RibbonGroup and see that it has a private property GroupSizeDefinitionsInternal that does the auto sizing. It always adds one definition with `IsCollapsed = true` so there is no way to do what I ask out.

A solution is to write code in your code behind to implement all your size definitions but without the `IsCollapsed = true` - note that the license states that you cannot use or modify the existing code so this needs to be written from scratch not copied from the property.